# Pytorch: torch.cuda.memory_allocated() returns 0 if PYTORCH_NO_CUDA_MEMORY_CACHING=1

Tags: python, memory-management, pytorch, gpu

There are clearly tensors allocated in my GPU memory. When I turn PYTORCH_NO_CUDA_MEMORY_CACHING enviroment variable back to 0 it works seemingly fine. Is this a bug?

I've read [pytorch documentation on memory management](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-memory-management) but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an [answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-cuda-memory-allocated-returns-0-if-pytorch-no-cuda-memory-caching-1/188796) on the Pytorch forum:

> Disabling the caching allocator is a debugging feature and some utils
> won’t work, such as CUDA Graphs. You could suggest a fix in case you
> are interested to see the used memory stats.